Wildly inconsistent performance of CP-SAT solver
I ran the CP-SAT solver three consecutive times on my model. The wall times were:

0h07m41s
0h39m45s
2h17m42s

There is almost 18x difference in runtime from the fastest to the slowest. There were no other CPU-intensive jobs on the machine at the time.
I understand there's some randomness in the solver, but I tried to remove that variation by seeding:
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.random_seed = 11111

Is this level of performance variation, given a fixed seed, reasonable?
(My goal is to get before-and-after performance measurements for some model changes I am considering. These were supposed to be the "before" numbers, but with this much variation, I will not have any confidence that the effects of my change will be visible.)
To recreate
I'm using ortools-9.10.4067 on Python 3.10.12 on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4.
git clone --branch inconsistent-solver-performance https://scottj97@bitbucket.org/scottj97/builderment.git
cd builderment
rm seeds/map_50resources.plants.json; make MAP=seeds/map_50resources

(Or download this exported model)
Solver elapsed wall time will appear in the log:
[2024-06-15 13:16:33.131512] Constraint solver completed after 2:17:42.137048.


can you just export the model and attach it ?

@LaurentPerron: added a link to exported model above

Yes. this is expected. This is a hard problem to make it fast and deterministic.
You can make the solver deterministic by setting the parameter interleave_search:true. But the impact on performance can be large.

I confirm that with interleave_search=True the solver is very consistent from run to run, though also about 2x slower than the slowest of my initial 3 runs.

Is this really a good system for benchmarking model changes? I.e. if I see a performance improvement with interleave_search=True is it safe to assume that performance has also been improved for the usual case (interleave_search=False)?

I do not know. Finding solutions boils down to luck. You are freezing luck with interleave_search = true. But the only measure of improvements I would consider involves a large set of problems, and possible multiple runs with different seeds for each problem.
